# How to alert users when no option is available angularjs dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, error-handling

In AngularJS I am making an $http call to populate a dropdown box.
In some cases the dropdown box will have no options to choose from, which would be equivalent to the code below

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [];
});
</script>
```

Right now when I run this code the user just sees nothing. 
I want to place a message in the dropdown box saying "No Data To Choose From".
In order to do this, do I have to bind the message as an `ng-option` or is there a cleaner way of doing it so it does not look like "No Data To Choose From" is a legit choice such as the code below makes it seem.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["no data to choose from"];
});
</script>
```

Basically if there are no options I want to let the user know in the cleanest way possible without binding the alert message as an option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an option tag with `ng-if` condition checking `names.length` inside select box. I added some button to populate/reset the select box data for testing this scenario.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [];
    
    $scope.loadData = function(){
      $scope.names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
<option value="" ng-if="!names.length">No data to choose</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="loadData()">load selectbox data</button>
<button ng-click="names=[]">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You may also want to have the `disabled` attribute on the option so it's not selectable

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for an error message next to / below the dropdown.

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
<small ng-show="!names.length">No data to choose from</small>

...

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [];
});
```